# Change input box 2 text as change in input box 1 Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two input box  Input box 1 and input box 2,
whenever I enter any aplhabate or word in input box 1 that should be type immediately in input box 2,

I tried in my way but doesn't got proper output.

Here is my HTML

```
<mat-form-field class="row">
    <mat-label>input Box 1 </mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="inputBox1" name="input box 1" [value]=""/>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="row">
    <mat-label>input Box 2 </mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="inputBox2" name="input box 2" [value]="" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

My TypeScript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
inputBox1:string='';
inputBox2:string='';


  onChange(event) {
    console.log("&&&&&&", event);
    this.inputBox2 =this.inputBox1;

  }

}
```

You can try on [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-box-change-value)

Comment: Do you need it should work vise-versa? I mean by changing value from textbox2 it should reflect textbox1?

Comment: not actually but if you do so , i will learn something new!

Comment: Then just use only one `[(ngModel)]` for both textbox, then no need to use any event or etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple thing if it serves your purpose. input1 value will be displayed in input2

```
<mat-form-field class="row">
    <mat-label>input Box 2 </mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="inputBox2" name="input box 2" [value]="inputBox1" (ngModelChange)="onHiveDbNameChange($event)" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Just change:

```
[value]="inputBox1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this without using `[(ngModel)]` or `onChange()`, input Box 1 value will be displayed in input Box 2

```
<mat-form-field class="row">
  <mat-label>input Box 1 </mat-label>
  <input matInput name="input box 1" #inputBox1 />
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="row">
  <mat-label>input Box 2 </mat-label>
  <input matInput  name="input box 2" [value]=inputBox1.value />
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place `(ngModelChange)="onHiveDbNameChange($event)"` in input box 1.

Like this:

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="inputBox1" name="input box 1" [value]="" (ngModelChange)="onHiveDbNameChange($event)"/>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-box-change-value-xqsrkb)**

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic model binding which angular does easy for you - You want to know only one thing pass the same property name for both the input fields like the code below

```
<mat-form-field class="row">
    <mat-label>input Box 1 </mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="inputBox" name="input box 1" />
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="row">
    <mat-label>input Box 2 </mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="inputBox" name="input box 2" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Just have one property `inputbox` and just map that property in both inputs like the code above - Hope it helps you Thanks!!